# How to find python class hierarchy across modules?

Tags: python, code-analysis

How to find class parent and subclasses across different modules without running the code (static analysis)

Module Contains `__init__.py` and 4 files as below

Example first_file.py

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        print('parent')
```

Example second_file.py

```
from first_file import Parent
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        print('child')
```

Example third_file.py

```
from first_file import Parent
class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        print('child1')
```

Example fourth_file.py

```
from second_file import Child
class Child2(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        print('child2')
```

I want the way to list down the subclasses of parent given filename and class
example

```
>>> findclasshierchay first_file.py --class Parent
```

and it will list down all subclasses with filenames

Comment: I know a way of dynamic analysis, is static analysis important for you? If it is, I think you can use builtin ``ast`` module.

Comment: Look at here: https://gist.github.com/EkremDincel/347ebe6c69bea159b3c6b68d7cb2722f

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL thanks for the above gist but this only works for the one file but as mentioned in the above example have subclasses across different files is there any for finding this statically? I know we can get the subclasses using `__subclasses__` attribute in python but I want to find subclasses without running the python code

Comment: have you looked at `<class>.mro()`?  combine that with a dynamic import like that provided by [django.utils.module_loading.import_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/utils/module_loading/)  and you're most of the way there.  each cls returned by `mro()` has 2 attributes of interest, `__name__` and `__module__`.

Comment: @user1640954 yes I know it don't works perfect, I wrote some comments about that. You can improve my example, you should add import check and modules of classes. You can look here for information about ``ast`` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at using `cls.mro()`.

Disclaimer, I don't know if you consider this to be *running the code* or not.  It's **not** static analysis, but if you have no great side effects upon module load, it really doesn't do that much either.

#### file1.py

```
class File1:
    pass
```

#### file2.py

```
from file1 import File1

class File2(File1):
    pass
```

#### listhier.py

```
import sys
import copy
import os
from importlib import import_module
from importlib.util import find_spec as importlib_find


#shamelessly copied from django 

def import_string(dotted_path):
    """
    Import a dotted module path and return the attribute/class designated by the
    last name in the path. Raise ImportError if the import failed.
    """
    try:
        module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
    except ValueError as err:
        raise ImportError("%s doesn't look like a module path" % dotted_path) from err

    module = import_module(module_path)

    try:
        return getattr(module, class_name)
    except AttributeError as err:
        raise ImportError('Module "%s" does not define a "%s" attribute/class' % (
            module_path, class_name)
        ) from err


toload = sys.argv[1]

cls = import_string(toload)

for cls_ in cls.mro():
    print("%s.%s" % (cls_.__module__, cls_.__name__))
```

`python listhier.py file2.File2`

#### output:

```
file2.File2
file1.File1
builtins.object
```